# Welsh vaccine card accepted as proof of vaccination when entering Canada?

Tags: canada, covid-19, denial-of-entry

I am travelling to Canada for 5 days on holiday in a week. I will be travelling on my US passport from Heathrow to Montreal.

I received both doses in Wales where I was given a Welsh vaccine card with handwritten details on the dates/kind/batch number as well as my name and date of birth.

I have been trying to get the NHS Covid Pass to work but currently it only shows the first dose, so while I can acquire/print a PDF with a QR code for dose 1, I cannot do the same for dose 2, or have a single "official" document stating I am fully vaccinated. I have been trying to rectify this for months without any progress.

Will the Welsh vaccine card be accepted? Will the card in addition to the 1st dose PDF be a good idea or more likely to be confusing and refused entry? Is there anything I can/should do in this situation?

Comment: Since the PDF is a confirmation of the first dose stated on the card, it may help for the second if there are doubts about the card.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thank you, I'll print it off then:)

Comment: Is your Welsh vaccine card bilingual?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be accepted. Vaccine verification is generally *extremely* lax when crossing international borders, so any official paper showing you have the right number of vaccinations will do just fine.